# Square root of BigDecimal

Tags: java, root, bigdecimal

Я искал решение квадратного корня для BigDecimal и нашел 2 варианта. Выполнил несколько тестов для обоих, они работают с 10 000 точностью.
Первый:

```
private static final int SCALE = 10001;

public BigDecimal calculate(BigDecimal number) throws OperationException {
    BigDecimal result;
    if (number.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) == 0 || 
            number.compareTo(BigDecimal.ONE) == 0) {
        result = number;
    } else if (number.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO)<0){
        throw new OperationException(NEGATIVE_VALUE_FOR_SQRT);
    } else {
       BigInteger integerValue = number.movePointRight(SCALE << 1).toBigInteger();
        int bits = (integerValue.bitLength() + 1) >> 1;
        BigInteger firstVar = integerValue.shiftRight(bits);
        BigInteger secondVar;
        do {
            secondVar = firstVar;
            firstVar = firstVar.add(integerValue.divide(firstVar))
.shiftRight(1);
        } while (firstVar.compareTo(secondVar) != 0);
        result = new BigDecimal(firstVar, SCALE);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Второй:

```
private static final int SCALE = 10001;

public BigDecimal calculate(BigDecimal number) throws OperationException {

    BigDecimal first = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    BigDecimal second;
    try{
        second = new BigDecimal(Math.sqrt(number.doubleValue()));
    }catch (NumberFormatException e){
        throw new OperationException(NEGATIVE_VALUE_FOR_SQRT);
    }
    while (!first.equals(second)){
        first = second;
        second = number.divide(first,SCALE,RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        second = second.add(first);
        second = second.divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(2),SCALE,RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    }
    return second;
}
```

Надеюсь, кому-то будут полезны;)

Comment: Добро пожаловать на SO на русском! Если вы хотите поделиться кодом, то лучше код ответа на вопрос поместить в ответе на него, а не в самом вопросе. Так будет понятнее посетителям вопроса и вы получите больше репутации за голоса на ответе (+10 против +5 на вопросе)

Comment: есть смысл поправить сейчас?

Comment: Вопрос имеет смысл править. Можете превратить его в «как считать квадратный корень BigDecimal» и опубликовать решения в отдельных ответах. Посмотрите [аналогичный вопрос на en.SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13649703/square-root-of-bigdecimal-in-java), заодно изучите альтернативные решения

Comment: Еще, я считаю что было бы хорошим тоном сначала опубликовать вопрос, затем дождаться ответов и уже потом публиковать свои решения, если они чем-то дополняют предложенные. Неотвеченные вопросы привлекают внимание, получают ответы и голоса. И Вам, и сообществу от этого будет только лучше.